# How can I improve the response time of this query in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, database-performance

this query takes 24 seconds and returns 1891 results:

```
SELECT p.STATE, p.REFNUM, p.CODE, p.TYPE, i.STATE, pj.NAME, pj.DOCUMENT
        TABLE p 
        inner join TABLE2 i on  i.REFNUM = p.REFNUM
        inner join TABLE3 pj on pj.NUMBER = i.NUMBER and p.OFIC_ID = pj.OFIC_ID and p.PUB_ID  = pj.PUB_ID 
        inner join OFICE o on t.OFIC_ID = p.OFIC_ID and o.PUB_ID = p.PUB_ID 
        inner join GROUP glad on glad.GROUP_CODE=p.GROUP_CODE
    WHERE glad.GROUP_TYPE ='3' AND i.STATE = '1'
        AND p.PUB_ID IN ('05','11','12','09','08','13','04','02','01','06','10','03','07','14')
        AND pj.NAME LIKE 'BANK%'
    ORDER BY o.NAME,p.ID;
```

I have these indexes:

```
    CREATE INDEX IND_TABLE1_REFNUM_ZONE ON TABLE1 (PUB_ID, OFIC_ID, REFNUM, ZONE_ID)
    CREATE INDEX IND_TABLE1_REFNUMPUB ON TABLE1 (REFNUM, PUB_ID, OFIC_ID, GROUP_CODE );
    CREATE INDEX IND_TABLE1_GROUP ON TABLE1 (PUB_ID, GROUP_CODE, REFNUM, OFIC_ID)
    CREATE INDEX IND_TABLE2_REF ON TABLE2 (REFNUM, NUMBER, STATE);
    CREATE INDEX IND_TABLE2_QUERY ON TABLE2 (NUMBER, TYPE, STATE, REFNUM, NUM, CODE);
    CREATE INDEX IND_TABLE2_REFNUM ON TABLE2 (REFNUM)
    CREATE INDEX IND_TABLE2_NUMBER ON TABLE2 (NUMBER)
    CREATE INDEX IND_TABLE3_NUM ON TABLE3 (NUMBER, PUB_ID, OFIC_ID, NAME );
    CREATE INDEX IND_TABLE3_NAME ON TABLE3 ( NAME );
    CREATE INDEX IND_GROUP_COD ON GROUP (GROUP_CODE, GROUP_TYPE)
```

I made the following queries to see how many records are in each table:

```
    SELECT count(*) FROM TABLE1  --> 18298458 results
    SELECT count(*) FROM TABLE2 --> 60627924 results
    SELECT count(*) FROM TABLE3 --> 18425913 results
    SELECT count(*) FROM OFICE --> 65 results
    SELECT count(*) FROM TABLE1 p INNER JOIN GROUP glad on glad.GROUP_CODE=p.GROUP_CODE where glad.GROUP_TYPE ='3' AND p.PUB_ID IN ('05','11','12','09','08','13','04','02','01','06','10','03','07','14') --> 1314077 results
    SELECT count(*) FROM TABLE1 p INNER JOIN GROUP glad on glad.GROUP_CODE=p.GROUP_CODE where glad.GROUP_TYPE ='3' AND p.PUB_ID IN ('05')  --> 53754 results
    SELECT count(*) FROM TABLE3 WHERE NAME LIKE 'BANK%' --> 1922081 results
```

this is the plan generated by oracle:

```
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Id  | Operation                                | Name                  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost  | Pstart| Pstop |
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                         |                       |   291K|    38M|   384K|       |       |
    |   1 |  SORT ORDER BY                           |                       |   291K|    38M|   384K|       |       |
    |   2 |   HASH JOIN                              |                       |   291K|    38M|   375K|       |       |
    |   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL                     | OFICE                 |    64 |   960 |     3 |       |       |
    |   4 |    HASH JOIN                             |                       |   291K|    34M|   375K|       |       |
    |   5 |     INDEX SKIP SCAN                      | IND_GROUP_COD         |    47 |   329 |     1 |       |       |
    |   6 |     HASH JOIN                            |                       |   452K|    50M|   375K|       |       |
    |   7 |      PART JOIN FILTER CREATE             | :BF0000               |   452K|    50M|   375K|       |       |
    |   8 |       NESTED LOOPS                       |                       |   452K|    50M|   375K|       |       |
    |   9 |        NESTED LOOPS                      |                       |       |       |       |       |       |
    |  10 |         STATISTICS COLLECTOR             |                       |       |       |       |       |       |
    |  11 |          HASH JOIN                       |                       |  2100K|   166M|   252K|       |       |
    |  12 |           NESTED LOOPS                   |                       |  2100K|   166M|   252K|       |       |
    |  13 |            STATISTICS COLLECTOR          |                       |       |       |       |       |       |
    |  14 |             PARTITION RANGE ALL          |                       |  1681K|    89M| 82582 |     1 |    19 |
    |  15 |              PARTITION HASH ALL          |                       |  1681K|    89M| 82582 |     1 |    32 |
    |  16 |               TABLE ACCESS FULL          | TABLE3                |  1681K|    89M| 82582 |     1 |   608 |
    |  17 |            INDEX RANGE SCAN              | IND_TABLE2_QUERY      |     1 |    27 |   103K|       |       |
    |  18 |           INDEX FAST FULL SCAN           | IND_TABLE2_QUERY      |    32M|   845M|   103K|       |       |
    |  19 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN                 | IND_TABLE1_REFNUM_ZONE|       |       |       |       |       |
    |  20 |        TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID| TABLE1                |     1 |    35 | 70380 | ROWID | ROWID |
    |  21 |      PARTITION RANGE ALL                 |                       |    19M|   650M| 70380 |     1 |    19 |
    |  22 |       PARTITION HASH JOIN-FILTER         |                       |    19M|   650M| 70380 |:BF0000|:BF0000|
    |  23 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL                 | TABLE1                |    19M|   650M| 70380 |     1 |   608 |
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

- I think it takes time because this one is using TABLE ACCESS FULL for TABLE1 and TABLE3
- if I perform the query filtering only PUB_ID='05' instead of all the numbers in the above query, the query returns 181 results and takes 8 seconds and in that case oracle generates this plan:

```
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Id  | Operation                              | Name                | Rows  | Bytes | Cost  | Pstart| Pstop |
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                       |                     |   797 |   108K|   312K|       |       |
    |   1 |  SORT ORDER BY                         |                     |   797 |   108K|   312K|       |       |
    |   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                         |                     |   797 |   108K|   312K|       |       |
    |   3 |    HASH JOIN                           |                     |  1238 |   160K|   312K|       |       |
    |   4 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| OFICE               |     3 |    45 |     2 |       |       |
    |   5 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | SYS_C0034405        |     3 |       |     1 |       |       |
    |   6 |     HASH JOIN                          |                     |  2091 |   240K|   312K|       |       |
    |   7 |      PART JOIN FILTER CREATE           | :BF0000             | 66316 |  5375K|   241K|       |       |
    |   8 |       NESTED LOOPS                     |                     | 66316 |  5375K|   241K|       |       |
    |   9 |        PARTITION RANGE ALL             |                     | 53085 |  2903K| 82490 |     1 |    19 |
    |  10 |         PARTITION HASH ALL             |                     | 53085 |  2903K| 82490 |     1 |    32 |
    |  11 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL             | TABLE3              | 53085 |  2903K| 82490 |     1 |   608 |
    |  12 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN                | IND_TABLE2_QUERY    |     1 |    27 |     3 |       |       |
    |  13 |      PARTITION RANGE ALL               |                     |   762K|    25M| 68657 |     1 |    19 |
    |  14 |       PARTITION HASH JOIN-FILTER       |                     |   762K|    25M| 68657 |:BF0000|:BF0000|
    |  15 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL               | TABLE1              |   762K|    25M| 68657 |     1 |   608 |
    |  16 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                    | IND_GROUP_COD       |     1 |     7 |     0 |       |       |
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

- SYS_C0034405 is the primary key of OFFICE which contains these fields: (PUB_ID, REG_ID)

- if in addition to filtering only PUB_ID='05' I remove the "order by", the query takes only 3.5 seconds but I definitely have to return the ordered data and I would prefer to be able to filter several PUB_IDs
- I thought the query could be improved if I removed the "inner join" from GROUP and changed the filter "glad.GROUP_TYPE ='3'" to "p.GROUP_CODE in ('01','07','10','21 ')" (these are all type 3 codes), because now it should use the IND_TABLE1_GROUP index but instead of improving, it gets worse, it takes 13 seconds even filtering only PUB_ID='05'; This is the plan that oracle generates:

```
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Id  | Operation                                          | Name                    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost  | Pstart| Pstop |
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                                   |                         |    47 |  6251 |   172K|       |       |
    |   1 |  SORT ORDER BY                                     |                         |    47 |  6251 |   172K|       |       |
    |   2 |   HASH JOIN                                        |                         |    47 |  6251 |   172K|       |       |
    |   3 |    PARTITION RANGE ALL                             |                         | 47786 |  2613K| 82490 |     1 |    19 |
    |   4 |     PARTITION HASH ALL                             |                         | 47786 |  2613K| 82490 |     1 |    32 |
    |   5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL                             | TABLE3                  | 47786 |  2613K| 82490 |     1 |   608 |
    |   6 |    HASH JOIN                                       |                         | 41945 |  3154K| 89633 |       |       |
    |   7 |     NESTED LOOPS                                   |                         | 41945 |  3154K| 89633 |       |       |
    |   8 |      NESTED LOOPS                                  |                         | 75740 |  3154K| 89633 |       |       |
    |   9 |       STATISTICS COLLECTOR                         |                         |       |       |       |       |       |
    |  10 |        NESTED LOOPS                                |                         | 18935 |   924K| 15985 |       |       |
    |  11 |         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED        | OFICE                   |     3 |    45 |     2 |       |       |
    |  12 |          INDEX RANGE SCAN                          | SYS_C0034405            |     3 |       |     1 |       |       |
    |  13 |         INLIST ITERATOR                            |                         |       |       |       |       |       |
    |  14 |          TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID BATCHED| TABLE1                  |  6312 |   215K|  7039 | ROWID | ROWID |
    |  15 |           INDEX RANGE SCAN                         | IND_TABLE1_GROUP         |  6828 |       |   284 |       |       |
    |  16 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                             | IND_TABLE2_REFNUM       |     4 |       |     2 |       |       |
    |  17 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                   | TABLE2                  |     2 |    54 |     4 |       |       |
    |  18 |     INDEX FAST FULL SCAN                           | IND_TABLE2_QUERY        |     2 |    54 |     2 |       |       |
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

- And if I put all the PUB_IDs, Oracle generates this plan (it doesn't even use the IND_TABLE1_GROUP index anymore):

```
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Id  | Operation                  | Name               | Rows  | Bytes | Cost  | Pstart| Pstop |
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT           |                    | 35661 |  4631K|   345K|       |       |
    |   1 |  SORT ORDER BY             |                    | 35661 |  4631K|   345K|       |       |
    |   2 |   HASH JOIN                |                    | 35661 |  4631K|   344K|       |       |
    |   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL       | OFICE              |    64 |   960 |     3 |       |       |
    |   4 |    HASH JOIN               |                    | 35661 |  4109K|   344K|       |       |
    |   5 |     PARTITION RANGE ALL    |                    |  1360K|    45M| 79580 |     1 |    19 |
    |   6 |      PARTITION HASH ALL    |                    |  1360K|    45M| 79580 |     1 |    32 |
    |   7 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL    | TABLE1             |  1360K|    45M| 79580 |     1 |   608 |
    |   8 |     HASH JOIN              |                    |  2100K|   166M|   252K|       |       |
    |   9 |      NESTED LOOPS          |                    |  2100K|   166M|   252K|       |       |
    |  10 |       STATISTICS COLLECTOR |                    |       |       |       |       |       |
    |  11 |        PARTITION RANGE ALL |                    |  1681K|    89M| 82582 |     1 |    19 |
    |  12 |         PARTITION HASH ALL |                    |  1681K|    89M| 82582 |     1 |    32 |
    |  13 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL | TABLE3             |  1681K|    89M| 82582 |     1 |   608 |
    |  14 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN     | IND_TABLE2_QUERY   |     1 |    27 |   103K|       |       |
    |  15 |      INDEX FAST FULL SCAN  | IND_TABLE2_QUERY   |    32M|   845M|   103K|       |       |
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because working code seeking improvement should be posted on the Code Review stack.

Comment: Indexes make sense almost only when they are very selective. Does any of your conditions reduce the amount to read from a table to, say, 1% or maybe even less? Are there only very few rows with GROUP_TYPE = 3? Are there only very few rows with STATE = 1? Are there only very few rows with the given PUB_IDs? I see that NAME LIKE 'BANK%' only reduces the rows to about 10%, so it makes no sense to think about a function index here. Maybe full table scans and hash joins are the best option for this query. In that case you could try a parallel hint to speed it up.

Comment: Put the values of the p.PUB_ID IN in a GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE with index and use it as the first table (driving table) in the FROM clause, joining on others, and create a function index on SUBSTR(TABLE3.NAME,1,4) and replace the LIKE 'BANK%' by SUBSTR(pj.NAME,1,4) = 'BANK'.